# Techelet on Talit Gadol not Talit Katan

Tags: halacha, tallit-gadol, tallit-katan, techeles

I don't have the money right now to equip all of my talitot katan with techelet, but I'd like to put it on my Talit Gadol (Please, no discussion of Techelet itself - I've made up my mind on that one).  Is is permissible to "mix and match" as it were?

Comment: I think some people davka put it on there talis only

Comment: Marc, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing your question here! I hope you'll look around and find other information here of interest as well, perhaps including our 18 other [tag:techeles] questions.

Comment: Isaac - Thanks.  I searched the techelet questions first.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [recommend](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1734/can-i-consult-mi-yodeya-as-i-would-a-rabbi) that you discuss your own situation and best course of action with your rabbi.

I posed this question, regarding my own entry into the techeilet world, to [Rabbi Jack Bieler](http://www.kmsynagogue.org/about-rabbi-bieler.html) in Silver Spring. If I recall correctly, he told me that if I only felt I could afford one set of strings, I should go ahead and put them on one garment, and that whether that would be the talit katan or talit gadol would be essentially my choice. His rationale was that fulfilling this mitzva with one garment is better than fulfilling it with none.

Comment: Thanks.  I just wanted a little more knowledge prior to asking.

Answer (score 0):

The Ibn Ezra in Yesod HaMora explains that the point of tzitzit is that goes with you around when you go out of the synagogue and helps you to remember the mitzvot of Hashem in your business dealings etc. Furthermore, we know that the ikkar of the mitzva and remembering is through the ptil techelet (Rashi, Rambam, et al.), this remembering is what allows us not to stray after our eyes and heart.

Hence, my recommendation is that if you need to choose between wearing it on the tallit katan or the tallit gadol at any moment, you may choose the tallit katan as you will wear the techelet which is the ikkar during the whole day. This way you would also be wearing it during the morning prayers, so it is only a win win situation.